# Show that $G$ is nilpotent when the quotient group is nilpotent

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, nilpotence

I want to show that if $H\subseteq Z(G)$ and $G/H$ is nilpotent then $G$ is also nilpotent.

$$$$

I have done the following:

Since $G/H$ is nilpotent there is a series of normal subgroups $$1\leq N_1\leq N_2\leq \cdots \leq N_k=G/H$$ with $N_{i+1}/N_i\subseteq Z((G/H)/N_i)$.

From the correspondence theorem we have that there is a bijective mapping between the subgroups of $G$ that contain $H$ and the subgroups of $G/H$, right?

Using this theorem could we take the preimage of the mappings that map to $N_i, i=1, \dots , k$ to get the corresponding series of normal subgroups $$1\leq \tilde{N}_1\leq \tilde{N}_2\leq \cdots \leq \tilde{N}_k=G$$ with $\tilde{N}_{i+1}/\tilde{N}_i\subseteq Z(G/\tilde{N}_i)$ ?

Comment: Almost. But the preimage of $1$ is not $1$ but $H$. So your series should start $1 \le H \le \tilde{N}_1 \le \cdots$, which gives a central series of $G$.

Comment: Why is the preimage of $1$ the group $H$ ? Also why is that a central series? @DerekHolt

Comment: The fact that the preimage of $1$ is $H$ is easy. Prove it yourself.

Comment: The bijective map is $\phi (A)\mapsto A/H, A\in G$, right? We get the subgroup of $G/H$, $1$, when $A=H$, right @DerekHolt

Comment: But why do we get a central series? @DerekHolt

Comment: We are told that $H \le Z(G)$.  Also $N_{i+1}/N_i \le Z(G/H)/N_i) \Rightarrow \tilde{N}_{i+1}/\tilde{N}_i \le Z(G/\tilde{N}_i)$. So it is a central serieis.

Comment: Ah ok... I see... Could we formulate it as follows? @DerekHolt  $$$$ From the correspondence theorem we have that there is a bijective mapping between the subgroups of $G$ that contain $H$ and the subgroups of $G/H$, $$\phi (A)\mapsto A/H, \ A\in G$$ 
We define $\tilde{N}_i:=\phi^{-1}(N_i), \ 1\leq i\leq k-1$. 
We have that $\phi^{-1}(1)=H, \ \tilde{N}_k=\phi^{-1}(N_k)=\phi^{-1}(G/H)=G$. 
$$$$ 
Therefore, we get the series of normal subgroups $$1\leq H\leq \tilde{N}_1\leq \tilde{N}_2\leq \cdots \leq \tilde{N}_k=G$$ with $\tilde{N}_{i+1}/\tilde{N}_i\subseteq Z(G/\tilde{N}_i), \ 1\leq i\leq k$.

Comment: Is everything correct? Could I improve something? @DerekHolt